# sort list tag according to date in jquery and handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I want to sort my list element according to date in jquery or javascript. I have done my code in handlebars, which I am posting below:

```
 <script id="template" type="text/html">
 <ul class="checklist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-autodividers="true">
 {{#container}}
{{#nid}}<li><a href="checklist-detail.html?nid={{nid}}">{{name}}-{{status}}{{#date}}<br />  
  <span class="due-date">{{date}}</span>{{/date}}</a></li>{{/nid}}
    {{/container}}
 </ul>
  </script>
```

Can any one help me sort the elements according to date?
I used javascript code (that is below) in another template for sort list element alphabetically and that is working fine:

```
 function sort()
  {             
 var mylist = $('ul');
 var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
 listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
 var compA = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
 var compB = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
 return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
 })
  $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date format is something that could be sorted alphabetically (e.g., ISO 8601 would render today's date as `2014-09-09`) then you can simply use the string value of the date as you have.

Otherwise, you'll have to parse the text as a date and compare them. JavaScript provides an easy way to do that for some date formats: `Date.parse()`. If your date strings are in a format that `Date.parse()` supports, then you can just create a sort function like so:

```
var sortByDate = function(a, b) {
  var compA = Date.parse($(a).text());
  var compB = Date.parse($(b).text());
  return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
};

function sort() {             
  var mylist = $('ul');
  var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
  listitems.sort(sortByDate);
  $.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
}
```

However, if it's in a non-supported format, you'll have to parse the date string yourself into its component parts, create a new Date() object for each item, and then compare those dates. Since you don't provide examples of your string representations, it's hard to know which approach is needed, but this should give you some pointers.